# CQL 3 Cassandra 1.2 counter: how to insert primary key?

Tags: cassandra, counter

I want to use a Cassandra counters in CQL3 like this

> create table count1 (id int PRIMARY KEY , c1 counter );

I know that in order to update the counter I need to do something of the form:

> update count1 set c1 = c1+1 where ..

but before this I need to insert a value in my `key (id);` but I get:

```
cqlsh:test2> insert into count1 (id) values (4);
Bad Request: INSERT statement are not allowed on counter tables, use UPDATE instead
```

what gives ?

Answer (score 8):

Cassandra doesn't have a concept of a primary key existing or not - it is only the cells that exist with a certain primary key.

So for normal column families (i.e. non-counter) you can `insert` or `update` (they are semantically identical) whether or not anything was previously inserted with that primary key.

As for counter tables, CQL requires you to use `update` rather than `insert`, to be clear that it is incrementing rather than setting the value. You cannot set a counter value in Cassandra, only inc/dec. If there was no previous counter, it is assumed to have value 0.  So you can run

```
update count1 set c1 = c1 + 1 where id = 2;
```

and the counter will have value 1:

```
select * from count1;

 id | c1
----+----
  2 |  1
```

Comment: Thanks Richard, I see, so I must update the counter table with an arbitrary id for this to work . Kind of peculiar, but that works - Thanks

Comment: It's the id for the counter that you use to retrieve it.  You can have as many as you want in the column family.